# How to get the counts of False in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below

```
no  out
20  True
3   False
3   False
```

How to get the counts of True and False

```
df.groupby(['out']).agg({'out':sum})



         out
out 
False   0.0
True    26.0
```

I am getting False count as 0

Comment: `df['out'].value_counts()` should do the trick.

Comment: `df.groupby('out',sort=False)['no'].sum()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df.groupby(['out'])['out'].count()
```

Comment: NameError: name 'count' is not defined

Comment: And what about this?